# NuxtJS - nuxtServerInit() issue with Vuex

Tags: typescript, vuex, nuxt.js

I try to use **nuxtServerInit** in Vuex actions.

I use `yarn dev` to start my project in development mode.

## actions.ts

```
import {ActionTree} from 'vuex';
import {StateType} from './state';

const actions: ActionTree<StateType, StateType> = ({
    nuxtServerInit () {
        console.log('test');
    }
});

export default actions;
```

The problem is `test` is not logged to the console.

I search to set my Vuex state posts with my database posts before to load the page of application. I don't know how I can to do this.

Comment: How are you exporting your actions, and which file are you exporting them from?  nuxtServerInit is only called from the root module.  ie: store/index.js

Comment: @HMilbradt I edited the post. I added the full code of actions.ts file. Thanks.

Comment: ```nuxtClientInit``` is not a function that is automatically called, only ```nuxtServerInit````.  If this is behaviour you'd like, I can show you how to achieve this.

Comment: nuxtServerInit will be called only on server, so u need to look at server logs not client